# React :: trocar parte de uma string por tag input

Tags: javascript, react

Vou descrever o que tenho no meu componente:
Recebo de uma API uma string com parte do conteúdo entre `*` e devo trocar essa parte do texto por um `<input />`. Pode ter mais de uma parte de conteúdo por string.

```
Ex: Lorem ipsum *dolor sit amet* |  Lorem ipsum <input />;
```

Estou usando essa função para trocar o que recebo da API por uma string especifica:

```
treatBlankQuestionsBlockStudent(text) {

    let blank = text.split('*');
    let finalBlank = [];

    blank.forEach((value, index) => {
      if (index % 2 === 0) {

        finalBlank.push(value);

      } else if (index % 2 !== 0) {

        let blank_parts = value.split(':');

        finalBlank.push('[insertInputHere]');
      }
    });

    return finalBlank;
  }
```

E no render do componente estou tentando fazer um `replace` dessa string `[insertInputHere]` pelo `<input />`:

```
<label> 
 <span>{alternativeIndex + 1}) </span>
   {textAlternative.map((t,index) => 
     <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: t.replace("[insertInputHere]", 
        <input 
           className="custom-input" 
           type="text"
           id={alternativeId+alternativeIndex}
           data-id={index}
           onChange={(event) => this.handleChange(event.target.value)}
        />
      )}} className="question-alternative-text" /> )}
</label>
```

Meu problema é o seguinte: não estou conseguindo renderizar o `<input />` de forma correta, ou retorna `[object Object]` ou não renderiza o `onChange`.

Qual a melhor forma para fazer essa renderização?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tens de passar ao JSX uma array. Usa o `.split` para remover os pedaços que não queres e depois adiciona a essa array os elementos que precisas (por exemplo com um `reduce`.

Ficaria assim (exemplo):

```js
const App = ({lorem}) => {
  const parts = lorem.split(/\*[^\*]+\*/g);
  const content = parts.reduce((arr, text, i, parts) => {
    if (i === parts.length - 1) return arr.concat(text);
    return arr.concat(text, <input type="text" />);
  }, []);
  
  return (<div>{content}</div>);
}

const lorem = 'Lorem *sfgffg* ipsum *dfggfd  sdgs  *.';
ReactDOM.render(
  <App lorem={lorem}/>, document.getElementById('app')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Entendi a logica que usou. Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.